# Run multiple commands in a single ssh session using popen and save the output in separate files

Tags: python, ssh, popen

I am trying to run several commands in a single ssh session and save the output of each command in a different file.

The code that works (but it saves all the output in a single file)

```
conn = Popen(['ssh',host, "ls;uname -a;pwd"], stdin=PIPE, stdout = open ('/output.txt','w'))
mypassword = conn.communicate('password')
```

Codes that I am trying to work but not working...

```
cmd = ['ls', 'pwd', 'uname']
conn = Popen(['ssh',host, "{};{};{}".format(cmd[0],cmd[1],cmd[2])], stdin=PIPE, stdout = output.append('a')) 
mypassword = conn.communicate('password')

print (output)
length = range(len(output))
print length
for i in output:
open("$i",'w')
```

and

```
cmd = ['ls', 'pwd', 'uname']
conn = Popen(['ssh',host, "{};{};{}".format(cmd[0],cmd[1],cmd[2])], stdin=PIPE, stdout = output())
mypassword = conn.communicate('password')

def output():

    for i in cmd:
        open(i,'w') 
    return
```

Not sure what is the best way of doing it. Should I save it in an array and then save each item in a separate file or should I call a function that will do it?
NOTE that the commands I want to run do not have small output like given in examples here (uname, pwd); it is big as tcpdump, lsof etc.

Answer (score 0):

A single ssh session runs a *single* command e.g., `/bin/bash` on the remote host -- you can pass input to that command to emulate running multiple commands in a single ssh session.

Your code won't run even a single command. There are multiple issues in it:

1. `ssh` may read the password directly from the terminal (not its stdin stream). `conn.communicate('password')` in your code writes to ssh's stdin therefore `ssh` won't get the password.

   There are multiple ways to authenticate via ssh e.g., *use ssh keys* (passwordless login).
2. `stdout = output.append('a')` doesn't redirect ssh's stdout because `.append` list method returns `None`.

   It won't help you to save output of several commands to different files. You could redirect the output to remote files and copy them back later: `ls >ls.out; uname -a >uname.out; pwd >pwd.out`.

   A (hacky) alternative is to use inside stream markers (`echo <GUID>`) to differentiate the output from different commands. If the output can be unlimited; learn how to read subprocess' output incrementally (without calling `.communicate()` method).
3. `for i in cmd: open(i,'w')` is pointless. It opens (and immediately closes on CPython) multiple files without using them.

   To avoid such basic mistakes, write several Python scripts that operate on local files.

Answer (score 0):

```
SYS_STATS={"Number of CPU Cores":"cat /proc/cpuinfo|grep -c 'processor'\n",
               "CPU MHz":"cat /proc/cpuinfo|grep 'cpu MHz'|head -1|awk -F':' '{print $2}'\n",
               "Memory Total":"cat /proc/meminfo|grep 'MemTotal'|awk -F':' '{print $2}'|sed 's/ //g'|grep -o '[0-9]*'\n",
               "Swap Total":"cat /proc/meminfo|grep 'SwapTotal'|awk -F':' '{print $2}'|sed 's/ //g'|grep -o '[0-9]*'\n"}


def get_system_details(self,ipaddress,user,key):
        _OutPut={}
        values=[]
        sshProcess = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','-T','-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no','-i','%s' % key,'%s@%s'%(user,ipaddress),"sudo","su"],
                                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True,bufsize=0)

        for element in self.SYS_STATS1:
            sshProcess.stdin.write("echo END\n")
            sshProcess.stdin.write(element)

        sshProcess.stdin.close()
        for element in sshProcess.stdout:
            if element.rstrip('\n')!="END":
                values.append(element.rstrip('\n'))
        mapObj={k: v for k, v in zip(self.SYS_STATS_KEYS, values)}

        return mapObj
```